# Updating driver to windows 10

Tags: windows, driver

I've been tasked with updating a driver from windows 7 to windows 10. I'm not talking about downloading the latest driver from the manufacturer, I'm talking about modifying the code so that we can update the driver (english is very ambiguous here).

I've managed to get the code to compile and build with visual studio 2019 and the latest SDK and WDK.

I've disabled the integrity checks on the computer.

When I try to update the driver on the device, and select my new driver, I get an error that "windows could not find drivers for your device".

Does anyone know what windows is checking here? Filename? Something in the file?

Also, does anyone have suggestions on anything else to try? Anyone else gone through this process and can offer advice?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-windows-driver#converting-an-existing-driver-project-to-a-windows-driver-project) or Linker > System > Minimum Required Version = 10.00

Comment: I followed the steps for method two "Create a new driver from a template". I would love to have followed method one, but there was no previous visual studio project. It was all done through the command line via build.

Comment: I did manage to get something that the installer would accept, but replacing the new .inf file with the original .inf file. The installer accepts it, but gets an access violation somewhere in the driver while trying to install and then windows crashes. I'm right now trying to figure out how to attach a debugger

Comment: Anyone know what windows is checking? How does it look at a driver and determine that it is, or is not, a driver for the device?